# Error installing mysql2: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2, ruby-2.2

I'm using (Mac Os)

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.0'             # rails edge
ruby '2.2.0'
gem 'mysql2'
```

After running `bundle` i got this error

> An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.17), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17'` succeeds
>   before bundling.

So as suggested i run

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17'
```

And i'm getting this error continuously, though i tried many solutions, unfortunately no luck

```
> adware:page365 apple$ gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17 ' Error loading
> RubyGems plugin
> "/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/yard-0.8.7.6/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb":
> can't modify frozen Hash (RuntimeError) Building native extensions.
> This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:   ERROR:
> Failed to build gem native extension.
> 
>     current directory: /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/ext/mysql2
> /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r
> ./siteconf20181030-12196-9cfizd.rb extconf.rb checking for
> ruby/thread.h... yes checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in
> ruby/thread.h... yes checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
> checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes checking for
> rb_hash_dup()... yes checking for rb_intern3()... yes
> ----- Using mysql_config at /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
> ----- checking for mysql.h... yes checking for errmsg.h... yes checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
> ----- Setting rpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/lib
> ----- creating Makefile
> 
> current directory:
> /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/ext/mysql2 make
> "DESTDIR=" clean
> 
> current directory:
> /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/ext/mysql2 make
> "DESTDIR=" compiling infile.c compiling client.c client.c:359:33:
> warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to
> 'unsigned int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
>         elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;
>                      ~ ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~ client.c:431:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'   my_bool res =
> mysql_read_query_result(client);   ^ client.c:433:19: error: use of
> undeclared identifier 'res'   return (void *)(res == 0 ? Qtrue :
> Qfalse);
>                   ^ client.c:762:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'   my_bool boolval;   ^ client.c:793:7: error: use
> of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
>       boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
>       ^ client.c:794:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
>       retval = &boolval;
>                 ^ client.c:797:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
>     case MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH:
>          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>          MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/include/mysql/mysql.h:188:3: note:
> 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here   MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,   ^
> client.c:798:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
>       boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
>       ^ client.c:799:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
>       retval = &boolval;
>                 ^ client.c:830:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
>         wrapper->reconnect_enabled = boolval;
>                                      ^ client.c:1163:56: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned
> long') to 'unsigned int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]   mysql2rb =
> mysql2_mysql_enc_name_to_rb(charset_name, charset_name_len);
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ client.c:1196:38: error: use of undeclared identifier
> 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?   return
> _mysql_client_options(self, MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH, value);
>                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                                      MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/include/mysql/mysql.h:188:3: note:
> 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here   MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,   ^ 2
> warnings and 10 errors generated. make: *** [client.o] Error 1
> 
> make failed, exit code 2
> 
> Gem files will remain installed in
> /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.17 for inspection.
> Results logged to
> /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.2.0/mysql2-0.3.17/gem_make.out
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Install gem after installing `mysql2` dependencies

```
brew install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: Thanks, it pointed me on the right direction (linux): `sudo apt install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev`

Answer (score -2):

To fix it, I just install the mysql2 gem it using bundler.

install mysql2 gem:

```
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec gem install mysql2
```