# unable to install mysql2 Gem on Bigsur

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, mysql2

I am using ruby 3.0.1p64
and using macOS bigsur 11.04
mysql installed and running

Bundle install asks me to install mysql2

I am trying to install mysql2 gem like this:

```
sudo gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

and I am getting this:

```
 Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/henri/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/ext/mysql2
/Users/henri/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/henri/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20210617-53969-y4phap.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdier
    --ruby=/Users/henri/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysqlclient-dir
    --without-mysqlclient-dir
    --with-mysqlclient-include
    --without-mysqlclient-include=${mysqlclient-dir}/include
    --with-mysqlclient-lib
    --without-mysqlclient-lib=${mysqlclient-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
/Users/henri/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `block in find_library': undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/henri/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `collect'
    from /Users/henri/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `find_library'
    from extconf.rb:87:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/henri/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-20/3.0.0/mysql2-0.5.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

and my mkmf.log looks like this:

```
    --------------------

have_func: checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... -------------------- yes

"clang -fdeclspec -o conftest -I/Users/henriknafo/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/include/ru$
conftest.c:14:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_wait_for_single_fd'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_wait_for_single_fd; ret$
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11:
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_wait_for_single_fd;$
/* end */
```

Could this be incompatible with ruby 3.0.1?
what library should I install so that mysql2 gem get's install

anyone having a suggestion?

Comment: Don't install gems with `sudo`. In addition to the security concerns you're just setting yourself up for future issues with file permissions. https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/why-you-should-never-use-sudo-to-install-ruby-gems/

Comment: Save issue, although not using `sudo`, of course.

Comment: If you're on a M1 / arm64 Mac, check out this Github Comment - it worked for me: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1175#issuecomment-910236422

Answer (score 17):

I installed mysql2 prior to bundle install and deleted the folder called .bundle prior to install:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- \
 --with-mysql-lib=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1/lib \
 --with-mysql-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1 \
 --with-mysql-config=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1/bin/mysql_config \
 --with-mysql-include=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1/include
```

Now I am good.

Comment: You might need to update your paths to point towards the version you have installed, but after that it works like a charm!

Comment: For intel Mac change paths to /usr/local/Cellar/

After many months my issue is finally resolved thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

1. Check if openssl installed.
2. install it if is not installed. `brew install openssl`
3. link it.  `brew link openssl`

you will get something like this.

```
 ➜ brew link openssl
Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl@1.1
If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH, run:
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

4. Copy

```
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
```

and

```
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

then run it.

6. `bundle install` again

It works in on my projects.

UPDATE:

1. `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/`
2. `bundle install`

might works.

Comment: Didn't work in my case. I still get the same error ld: library not found for -lssl

Comment: Ediited answer.

Comment: This worked for me doing an install on Monterrey.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. I am using macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 1):

Im using Macbook OS Big Sur and this worked for me:

```
brew install openssl
brew link openssl

  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"

bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"

bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what worked for me:

brew install openssl

brew link mysql

Comment: Now when I start rails s... I get an error saying: An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need libmysqlclient-dev
Take a look at last comment (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53081763/7205276) on [Error installing mysql2: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061931/error-installing-mysql2-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension) thread

Comment: I tried to brew install libmysqlclient-dev and it did not find the library. I even installed mysql-connector-c and not working.